# Three-leaved Aswatha Tree in Hindu iconography

Tags: shiva, history, pashupata-shaivism, research

The three-leaved pipal tree , or Aswatha, seems to appear on one of the Pashupati Seal discovered in Mohenja-Daro.

Are there any recent, or related representation of this tree/leaves in any Hindu iconography over the head of the divinity like in this (possible, but is not very clear) seal?

[image]